# Catch exception from ServiceBusTrigger Azure function v4 out of process(isolated, worker)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-functions-isolated

I have a dotnet worker azure function v4 (aka isolated, out of process).

I have a serviceBusTrigger for which I listen for new messages published.

I want to create a subscription at the startup of the azure function, I am using the Program.cs and HostBuidler approach to set up the DI.

I am using the following code and it works fine:

```
    IHost host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
    {
      // omitted for brevity
    })
    .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
    {
        // omitted for brevity
    })
    .Build();

// here I am creating a subscription if not exist
ServiceBusAdmin serviceBusAdmin = new();
await serviceBusAdmin.CreateOrUpdateAzureServiceBusSubscriptionsAsync();

await host.RunAsync();
```

The problem I encounter is that the ServiceBussTrigger tries to connect to the AzureServiceBuss before bootstrapping is completed. And shows a lot of errors in the terminal like the following:
`[2023-02-13T] System.Private.CoreLib: The messaging entity ':Topic:my-topic|my-sub' could not be found. To know more visit https://aka.ms/sbResourceMgrExceptions.  TrackingId:2c20, SystemTracker:'Topic:my-topic|my-sub', Timestamp:2023-02-13T15:12:36 TrackingId:043a, SystemTracker:gateway7, Timestamp:2023-02-13T15:12:36 (MessagingEntityNotFound).`

What I want to do is to make sure I can create the subscription in the azure function side, and handle somehow the errors.

I scattered the internet to find some info and looked at the official repository for dotnet worker to find some event I could subscribe to to catch the exception, but couldn't find any.

P.S: 'Topic:my-topic|my-sub' name is renamed because it contains name from company I work for.

Comment: Is your ASB trigger configured to connect `my-topic|my-sub`?

Comment: I removed the info because it contains info about company I work for.

Comment: The code will not throw any exceptions after running the method for subscription code:  CreateOrUpdateAzureServiceBusSubscriptionsAsync

Comment: The name of the topic and subscription are irrelevant. Are you creating the topic/subscription _before_ you run the Function? It's a chicken and egg situation. You can't have an ASB trigger w/o the entity.

Comment: The Topic is created from another app/function which is the publisher, when we publish the topic we make sure it is created/exists in that service bus connection. Ideally, we don't want to create a subscription from the publisher app, we want it so that the publisher will not know about the subscribers/consumers.

Comment: I want to do what are you saying, run code: before the azure function start/or when is it bootstrapping in order to create the subscription to that topic. But SBT  throws the exception mentioned in the description even if the HostBuilder is fully started.

Comment: The trigger is expecting the topic and subscription to be in place. I've done something similar with the In-Proc SDK for [queue](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/automatic-queue-creation-for-function) and [subscription](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/automatic-nservicebus-topology-creation-for-function) in the past. I suspect the Isolated Worker SDK approach would be similar, but I don't know if you have the opportunity window since the host is a different process, and it might be too late to try and create the entity at that point. Ask in github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker

Comment: Also, I suspect your code is coming in too late. It should likely be before `HostBuilder` is done building.

Comment: I tried to do it before HostBuilder is done building, same behavior will leave it like this because I can't find how to solve it programmatically. Maybe if it will became an issue for us we could create the subscription when the deployment is done through azure devops. Thanks!